# RegEx: match line breaks or spaces between square brackets

Tags: python, regex

How can I find all line breaks or spaces that are inside square brackets?

I have the following string:

```json
{
  "decay_id": {
    "int_only": true,
    "feature_type": "categorical",
    "category_values": [
      0,
      1
    ],
    "category_names": [
      "d1",
      "d2"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want to delete line breaks and spaces so that I get:

```json
{
  "decay_id": {
    "int_only": true,
    "feature_type": "categorical",
    "category_values": [0,1],
    "category_names": ["d1","d2"]
  }
}
```

How can I use RegEx (and Python) to do this?

Something like:

```py
import re

output = re.sub("some RegEx", "", input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re

output = re.sub(r"\[[^][]*]", lambda z: re.sub(r'\s+', '', z.group()), input)
```

**See [Python code](https://tio.run/##XU/NisIwEL7nKYa5tHWDrHoT9klqt8R21ELbhMlkIYrPXqMtwnqYv@9nmHFRLnbcTVM3OMsCTEp5@AFGxJsCwJYaE@uuxT0854R0o9R27GNChAPpGT2RkcBUS3SUGGyM0Nly15geF8kCxfrP9IF8UpUvAuBbL83mVatPw2iGf3psN6jf/RZnV8p3dU@HKxvEBXm@QWsfjjnjoSx/q7JaVaihN8OxNXDdv@ns4L8yDVmK6/rMNri8KDT4QinH6d98XlhM0wM)**

**Results**:

```
{
  "decay_id": {
    "int_only": true,
    "feature_type": "categorical",
    "category_values": [0,1],
    "category_names": ["d1","d2"]
  }
}
```